# $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\arctan^2 \left ( \sin^2 x \right )}{\sin^2 x} \, {\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does anyone have any ideas on how to attack this:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\arctan^2 \left ( \sin^2 x \right )}{\sin^2 x} \, {\rm d}x$$

I cannot think of something that could work. Wolfram Alpha does not evaluate it either.

Comment: What makes you think there even is a solution in elementary functions?

Comment: This integral was proposed by M.L.Glasser so I guess it has. I don't know where it was proposed though neither do I know any other details.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741089/closed-form-of-int-0-pi-2-frac-arctan2-sin2-theta-sin2-theta

Comment: No way I would have derived that answer!.. Way beyond my league! Thanks @nospoon

Comment: @Tolaso Sure. You do ask very interesting questions, so keep it up.